# Wordpress - Automatic email to admin on password change

Tags: wordpress

Noticed something interesting in WordPress...hopefully its just me not seeing the right option.

Whenever a user requests a new password, it will notify the site admin that the password was changed. What I'd like to do is disable this feature, as for this specific site I really don't care if users are changing their password.

Is this a setting somewhere that I'm missing, or does it require a plugin to disable this functionality?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I also changed the registration to create and email a password. So when they change it to whatever they want it emails me that their password was lost and then changed. I'm wondering if there's a way to disable the notification as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a simple pluging that overwrites wp_password_change_notification.

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wp_password_change_notification' ) ) {
    function wp_password_change_notification() {}
}
```

More detailed instructions can be found here:

http://wpquicktips.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/disable-password-changedreset-e-mail-notification/

Comment: Does this affect the user-facing notification, too? Or simply the admin notification?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see anything in WP 3.0 that did what you wanted.

The Register Plus plugin *almost* gives you what you want.  It allows you to disable registration notifications.  Maybe drop the developer a line to see if he can add what you want?

Comment: I'm a bit behind and am running WP2.8 on this specific site.  I'll check out the plugin though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have put together a plugin that disables the sending of "password changed notification" email:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disable-password-change-email/

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think that's part of standard WP procedure. Only the user resetting the password usually gets an email about the reset.

I've never received an email for any of my users resetting their passwords.

Are you sure it's not people trying to reset the admin password, and that's why you're getting emails?

Comment: The person designated as my site admin received an email that another user had changed his password.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is in the setting where you put your email to be notify for any activity that the admin should be notify, such as if there is any ping or link back to your site, any new registration to your site or even any "FORGOT PASSWORD" or password change that happen to your site.

I'm afraid that if you want to disable this there is only two option

1. Remove your email from the database [Hardcore removing] because in Wordpress setting it doesn't allow you to remove because it is required.
2. Is you have to add this in your functions.php which will disable the whole notification.

.

```
if( function_exists('wp_password_change_notification') )
    function wp_password_change_notification(){}
if( function_exists('wp_password_change_notification') )
    function  wp_new_user_notification(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found better solution for solve this problem without plugin.

1. Backup your wp-includes/pluggable.php
2. Edit wp-includes/pluggable.php file
3. Find wp_password_change_notification part
4. Delete these lines from file:

   ```
   if ( !function_exists(`wp_password_change_notification`) ) 

       /**
        * Notify the blog admin of a user changing password, normally via email.
        *
        * @since 2.7.0
        *
        * @param object $user User Object
        */

       function wp_password_change_notification(&$user) {

       // send a copy of password change notification to the admin
       // but check to see if it's the admin whose password we're changing, and skip this
       if ( 0 !== strcasecmp( $user->user_email, get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) ) {
           $message = sprintf(__('Password Lost and Changed for user: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n";
           // The blogname option is escaped with esc_html on the way into the database in sanitize_option
           // we want to reverse this for the plain text arena of emails.
           $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);
           wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] Password Lost/Changed'), $blogname), $message);
       }
   ```

   `}    endif;`
5. Save.

Comment: THat will work, but a better idea is to just comment it out with /* (code) */ in case you ever want to reverse this.  Also keep in mind that updates may over-write your changes.